# Name for the "stronger submodularity" property in cut function

Tags: co.combinatorics, submodularity

Let $f:2^V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a set function over $V$ that satisfies the following:

1. $f(A \cap B) + f(A \cup B) \le f(A) + f(B)$
2. $f(A \backslash B) + f(B \backslash A) \le f(A) + f(B)$.

> Here are the questions:
>
> 1. Cut function $c(\delta(\cdot))$ is known to satisfy both 1) and 2). Is there any other natural example of function satisfying both ?
> 2. If $f$ satisfies 1), then we say $f$ is submodular. But is there a name for the property of function satisfying both 1) and 2) ? Or only 2) ?

Comment: According to this lecture note: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs598csc/sp2010/Lectures/Lecture6.pdf , the second property is called posi-modular which is followed from symmetric submodularity.